# My function returns the catch all when i'm passing a string that fits the parameters I've tried to set. How to proceed?

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

I’m running into a wall on the second step of this project. My console test returns as “Card number not recognized” when I put in a Visa or MasterCard number, and the intent is for it to detect which network the card number is from. Any insight you could afford me would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var detectNetwork = function(cardNumber) {
  // Note: `cardNumber` will always be a string
  var splt = cardNumber.split('');
  // The Diner's Club network always starts with a 38 or 39 and is 14 digits long
  if ((splt[0] === '3') && (splt[1] === '8' || splt[1] === '9') && (splt.length === 14)) {
    return 'Diner\'s Club';
  } else if ((splt[0] === '3') && (splt[1] === '4' || splt[1] === '7') && (splt.length === 15)) {
    return 'American Express';
  } else if ((splt[0] === '4') &&
    (splt.length === 13 ||
    splt.length === 16 ||
    splt.length === 19)) {
    return 'Visa';
  } else if ((splt[0] === '5') &&
    ((splt[1] === '1') || (splt[1] === '2') || (splt[1] === '3') ||
    (splt[1] === '4') || (splt[1] === '5')) &&
    (splt.length === 16)) {
    return 'MasterCard';
  } else {
    return 'Card number not recognized';
  }
  // The American Express network always starts with a 34 or 37 and is 15 digits long

  // Once you've read this, go ahead and try to implement this function, then return to the console.
};
```

Comment: Could you add to your code a few calls of this function, with actual arguments that do not give the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a bunch of IFs, I would rather to use `RegExp` so it is easier to follow what you want to achieve.

Additionally to that, before checking the string I also recommend to clean it, so in case you get something like:

`1234-1234.1234 1234$1234`

it will cleaned and you will get something like:

`12341234123412341234`

and it is easier to check if it really matches

here you have all my recommendations applied and working, I put an example of each of the cases, along with this you can see that the first 1/2 digits are separated, so you can recognize it better.

```js
const replacer = /[^\d]/g;
const dinnersRegex = /^3(8|9)\d{12}$/;
const americanRegex = /^3(4|7)\d{13}$/;
const visaRegex = /^4(\d{18}|\d{15}|\d{12})$/;
const masterRegex = /^5(1|2|3|4|5)\d{14}$/;

var detectNetwork = function(cardNumber) {
  // lets replace all weird characters BUT numbers.
  const cleanNumber = cardNumber.replace(replacer, "")

  if (dinnersRegex.test(cleanNumber)) {
    return 'Diner\'s Club';
  } else if (americanRegex.test(cleanNumber)) {
    return 'American Express';
  } else if (visaRegex.test(cleanNumber)) {
    return 'Visa';
  } else if (masterRegex.test(cleanNumber)) {
    return 'MasterCard';
  } else {
    return 'Card number not recognized';
  }
};

// used some weird symbols to use the cleaner and see if it works.
console.log("diners1:", detectNetwork("38--12-1231-1234-12"))
console.log("diners2:", detectNetwork("39--12-1231-1234-12"))

console.log("american1:", detectNetwork("34 121231 1234 129"))
console.log("american2:", detectNetwork("37 121231 1234 129"))

console.log("visa1:", detectNetwork("4  712.1231.1234.1291.123"))
console.log("visa2:", detectNetwork("4  712123112341298"))
console.log("visa3:", detectNetwork("4  712123112341"))

console.log("master1:", detectNetwork("5  112123112341291"))
console.log("master1:", detectNetwork("5  212123112341291"))
console.log("master1:", detectNetwork("5  312123112341291"))
console.log("master1:", detectNetwork("5  412123112341291"))
console.log("master1:", detectNetwork("5  512123112341291"))

console.log("unrecognized:", detectNetwork("9812311234129"))
```